# change swagger UI in wso2 api manager 1.9

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am new in wso2 api manager 1.x , recently we have set up the wso2 api manager 1.9 in one of our server , it looks good as well .

So , we are moving further to change the UI in api console (api store). for example - as i can see there is a [soap Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRzE5.png)  , we want its default value to API name ,,Is there any way to do the same .??

i am doing by changing swagger-ui.js but it seems not working for me ,

please help into this

Thanks

Comment: In the that page it's loaded wagger-ui.min.js where it's the min version. You will have to build the min version of swagger-ui.js to fix it. We are using min.js to reduce the size

Comment: Build .??
and how to build that min version js .. as i have no idea about this .